# (C++) Recursive call to file input function

Tags: c++, file, recursion, input

I have function used to input a file and store the contents in a string.

Here is the code

```
    std::string inputFile();

    int main()
    {
        std::string fileContents = inputFile();
    }

    std::string inputFile()
        {
            std::string fileName;
            std::cout << "\nEnter file name, including path:\n";
            std::getline(std::cin, fileName);

            std::ifstream input(fileName.c_str());
            std::string buffer;
            std::string result; 

            if (!input.fail()) // if input does not fail
            {
                while (!input.eof()) 
                {
                    std::getline(input, buffer); 
                    result.append(buffer); 
                }
                input.close();

                return result; 
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << "\nInvalid file name or path";
                inputFile(); // recursive call to inputFile
            }
        }
```

It works fine if the file name and path is input correctly.

But, if the file name or path is entered incorrectly, the recursive call to inputFile is executed, and the user is given another opportunity to enter the file. Then, if the file name is entered correctly an error is thrown in Visual Studio 2013:

"Unhandled exception at 0x77F7A9E8 (msvcr120d.dll) in Assignment4.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCCCCCCC0."

Thank you for any suggestions

Comment: what have you debugged for now ? any info ?

Comment: A `while` or `do/while` loop would probably be a better fit here than recursion.

Comment: ...and I can all-but-guarantee this: `while (!input.eof()) ` is wrong regardless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I'm about to say is technically an answer, since if you do this, you'll avoid the issue that was causing the error that caused you to post.  But since it says "rewrite all of your assumptions", it would be better as a comment.  Since I can't make it look pretty as a comment, here goes.

**Using recursion here is wrong**

A recursive function continually calls itself for processing until it hits a well-determined endpoint.  There are cases (tree or graph walking are the ones that most immediately jump to mind) where it's the ideal solution.  There are other cases (the typical lesson in the Fibonacci sequence, e.g.) where it's an acceptable solution, though doesn't really have any benefit.  And there are many cases where it is wrong to use it.

This is one of the latter.

The problem with recursion is that none of the calls to the recursive function returnsuntil you hit the terminating condition and everything folds back into itself. So, let's say you hit the `input.fail` case, and recurse back into `inputFile`.  You now have two instances of `inputFile` in your call stack.  The first one that recursed and is waiting for the response, and the second one, which will check `input.fail`.  If this second one hits an input failure as well, you'll now have three instances in memory, and on and on.  ***On any system, there will be some limit where you have too many functions on the stack***.  When you reach this point, the program will run out of memory, and you'll actually get an exception called a Stack Overflow.  You're not necessarily guaranteed to hit this point, but by using recursion, you're adding the vulnerability for this to happen to your program.

**What's the right way?**

The right way is to always have your `inputFile` function return, so you won't be adding a potentially unlimited number of calls to your stack.

Here's the right way to do your code (I'll use your code as verbatim as possible, not fixing other issues like the ones mentioned by Joachim Pileborg):

```
std::string inputFile();

int main()
{
    std::string fileContents;
    while (fileContents.empty()) {
        fileContents = inputFile();
    }
}

std::string inputFile()
    {
        std::string fileName;
        std::cout << "\nEnter file name, including path:\n";
        std::getline(std::cin, fileName);

        std::ifstream input(fileName.c_str());
        std::string buffer;
        std::string result; 

        if (!input.fail()) // if input does not fail
        {
            while (!input.eof()) 
            {
                std::getline(input, buffer); 
                result.append(buffer); 
            }
            input.close();
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "\nInvalid file name or path";
        }

        return result; 
    }
```

The difference is that I got rid of recursion.  `main` now checks the response from `inputFile`, and `inputFile` doesn't call itself and always returns a value.  You'll never have more than one instance of `inputFile` being executed at a time, and your call stack will never have more than 2 functions in it.

It's cleaner code, too: every function should be responsible for doing one task.  `inputFile` reads a file and returns a result.  It's not `inputFileRepeatedlyUntilSuccessful`.

It makes more sense to have a controlling function (in this case, `main`), that checks to see if the function succeeded than to have the function perpetually calling itself.

Recursion has its place, but potentially infinite loops requiring user feedback is not it.

Answer (score 5):

You have undefined behavior, as in the `else` case you don't return anything.

Besides, this is probably better handled with a loop than recursion.

---

By the way, you should not do `while (!input.eof()) ...`, it does not work as you expect. The reason being that the EOF flag isn't set until *after* an input operation fails, so you will have a failed input operation which you don't check for before noticing that you have reached the end of the file.

The solution to this is to use the facts that `std::getline` returns the stream, and a stream object can be used as a boolean to check that everything is okay:

```
while (std::getline(...)) { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but how would I write that--what goes in place of the ellipses?

Comment: @navig8tr The stuff you have now.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use a loop than recursion, because your code leads to undefined behavior.

It can be done like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>


std::string inputFile()
{
    std::string fileName;
    std::ifstream input;
    std::string buffer;
    std::string result; 

    while(true)
    {
        std::cout << "\nEnter file name, including path:\n";
        std::getline(std::cin, fileName);
        input.open(fileName);
        if (input.fail()) // if input fails ask for another filename
        {
            std::cout << "\nInvalid file name or path";
        }
        else break;// if the file exists break the loop
    }
    //read the contents
    while (getline(input, buffer)) 
    {
        result.append(buffer); 
    }
    input.close();
    return result; 
}

int main() 
{
    std::string fileContents = inputFile();
    std::cout << fileContents << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The recursion itself is not the undefined behavior.  Even if the function recursed properly, and didn't cause undefined behavior, recursion would still be a bad solution to this problem.